# Azure continuous deployment always fails

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-devops

Using VSO Team Project and Azure Web App.
I want to connect these services together, however, when I set up Continuous deployment it always fires this error:
[image]

My subscription is free DreamSpark.

What can I do?

Comment: It's a permissions issue. Did you use the same account for the site and the team Project?

Comment: In VS online I am logged in with my personal account, same as in azure. But maybe, there is some issue between dreamspark subscription and personal account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting up CI with VSO TFS is not supported for Dream spark subs. It looks like we have a bug in the UI if you are getting this far.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear if you were using VSO-TFS or VSO-GIT. Unfortunately either one of them are not supported for Dreamspark subscriptions